# How to interpolate complex array (FT)?

Tags: image-processing, fft, interpolation

I do Fourier Transform for an image, then consider line(slice) in FFT image. When that slice isn't parallel neither x- not y-axis, coordinates are not integer.
E.g. slice can hold indices `{(0,0), (0.25,1), (0.5,2), (0.75,3), (1,4)...}`.
When using nearest-interpolation, quality of whatever I do is pure.

What techniques can you suggest to improve interpolation in Fourier grid?

Comment: Welcome to DSP.SE!  I'm not sure what you mean by "When using nearest-interpolation, quality of whatever I do is pure." Could you rephrase it?

Comment: @Peter K. : I want to calculate invertible Radon transform using Projection-Slice theorem. So, when for point `(0.75, 3)` use value at `(1,3)`, and then perform inverse transform, reconstruction is not perfect.

Comment: Are all your coordinates multiples of 0.25 or such?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usual way to do this is to interpolate using surrounding points.  There is a simple 6-point mechanism that uses:

[image]

[This question on the Mathematics SE site has some more details.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/72155/how-to-interpolate-a-2d-function-with-6-points) Note the answer's correction to the equation in the question.